# how to use jquery validator to determine value of one field is greater than another field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields in a form and I want to add a rule for them saying that
id2 cannot have value less than id1

```
 <input type="text" id="id1">
 <input type="text" id="id2">


id1 : {
                number: true,
                min: 0
            }, 
id2 : {
                number: true,
                min: 0
            }
```

Is there a way to set the rule for the jquery validator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add a custom method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",
    function (value, element, param) {
          var $otherElement = $(param);
          return parseInt(value, 10) > parseInt($otherElement.val(), 10);
    });
);
```

The above code assumes you are using integers. If not, replace `parseInt` with `parseFloat`.

Then use it this way in your configuration:

```
id2: {
    number: true,
    min: 0,
    greaterThan: "#id1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, these elements are not required elements and the error now shows up even if these fields are empty.
So now i used: 
if(!value)
      return true; inside the custom method.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the desired behavior with jQuery using the following :

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="id1">
 <input type="text" id="id2">
 <input type="submit" id="submit">
 <div class="error" style="display:none">id2 cannot have value less than id1<div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#id2").focusout(function(){

    if(parseFloat($("#id1").val()) > parseFloat($("#id2").val()))
    {
        $(".error").css("display","block").css("color","red");
        $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
    }
    else {
        $(".error").css("display","none");
        $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);        
    }

});
```

See the jfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fyrgazfg/